# ¿Cómo conocer en dónde se ubican los querys en mi aplicación web?

Tags: java, javascript, html

Tengo una aplicación web desarrollada bajo maven con el framework Spring y el servidor de aplicaciones en el que se desplega es weblogic que realiza consultas a una base de datos en un servidor. Viendo el código en el index, no logro descubrir cómo manda y qué query manda para realizar las consultas a la base de datos.

En el siguiente código se encuentra el metodo que se supone realiza la búsqueda, al darle clic al botón buscar:

```
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="informacionProducto()" class="buscar">Buscar</a>
<a href="#" onclick="limpiarTablas()" class="buscar">Limpiar</a>
<input type="hidden" name="IpCC" id="IpCC" value="" class=""/>

<div id="loading">
    <p>Buscando producto,</p>
    <p> por favor espere... </p>
```

Y acá está el código de ese método

```
function informacionProducto() {
    $("#loading").show();
    var formulario = $('#formularioBusqueda');

    if (document.formularioBusqueda.radio2.checked) {
        var x = 0;
        $.post(
            'ConsultasRms/tabla_consultaProductoPromocion.html',
            formulario.serialize(),
            function (data) {
                $("#loading").hide();
                if (data.rows[0].length == 0 && data.rows[1].length == 0) {
                    $("#dialog-NoDataPromocion").dialog("open");
                }
                else {
                    //borramos el contenido de los option del select
                    //$("#comboboxSucursales").html("");
                    //recorremos todas las filas del resultado del proceso que obtenemos en Json
                    comboSucursales = document.getElementById('comboboxSucursales');
                    sucursalConsulta = comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].text;
                    var listaProductoActivo = data.rows[0];
                    for (x = 0; x < listaProductoActivo.length; x++) {
                        var datarow = {
                            sucursal: sucursalConsulta,
                            numeroSucursal:comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].value,
                            ip: ipControlador,
                            sistema: tipoSucursal,
                            codigoPrincipal: listaProductoActivo[x].codigoPrincipal,
                            descripcionCorta: listaProductoActivo[x].descripcionCorta,
                            precio: listaProductoActivo[x].precio,
                            precioPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].precioPromocion,
                            pvJusto: listaProductoActivo[x].pvJusto,
                            statusProducto: listaProductoActivo[x].statusProducto
                        };
                        datarowRmsDetalle[cont] = {
                            descripcionLarga: listaProductoActivo[x].descripcionLarga,
                            iva: listaProductoActivo[x].iva,
                            estado: listaProductoActivo[x].estado,
                            departamento: listaProductoActivo[x].departamento,
                            codigoComponente: listaProductoActivo[x].codigoComponente,
                            codigoPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].codigoPromocion,
                            fechaInicioPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].fechaInicioPromocion,
                            fechaFinPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].fechaFinPromocion
                        };


                        var su = jQuery("#tablaProductoRms")
                                        .jqGrid('addRowData', cont,
                                        datarow);

                        cont++;
                    }

                    var inactivo = "";
                    var listaProductoInactivo = data.rows[1];
                    if (listaProductoInactivo.length > 0) {
                        for (x = 0; x < listaProductoInactivo.length; x++) {

                            inactivo = inactivo + "<li>" + listaProductoInactivo[x].codigoPrincipal + "</li>"
                        }
                        $("#etiquetaMensajeInactivo").html(inactivo);
                        $("#dialog-DataProductoInactivo").dialog("open");
                    }
                }
            }, "json");
```

No veo en dónde está el query ni ningún archivo al que haga referencia.

---

del lado de backend encontre este codigo

```
@RequestMapping("/tabla_consultaProductoPromocion")
public ModelAndView consultaProductoPromocion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                  @RequestParam("buscarProductoInput") String codigoPromocion,
                                                  @RequestParam("comboboxSucursales") String sucursal,
                                                  @RequestParam("IpCC") String ipControlador
    ) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Antes de la ejecutar consultaProductoPromocion" + codigoPromocion + ", " + sucursal + ", "
                + ipControlador);
        codigoPromocion = codigoPromocion.replace(" ", "");
        IConsultaProductosRms consultaRms = new ConsultaProductosRms();
        List<String> listaBarra = consultaRms.consultaProductosPromocion(em, codigoPromocion, sucursal);

        List<List<Producto>> listaP = new ArrayList<List<Producto>>();

        listaP.add(0, crearListaProducto(sucursal, consultaRms, listaBarra, "2"));

        listaBarra = consultaRms.consultarProductosPromocionInactivos(em, codigoPromocion, sucursal);

        listaP.add(1, crearListaProducto(sucursal, consultaRms, listaBarra, "1"));


        logger.info("Despu\u00E9s de la ejecutar consultaProductoPromocion retorna: "+ listaP);
        return new ModelAndView("tabla_consultaProductoPromocion", "lista", listaP);
    }
}
```

por lo que veo realiza las consultas, pero no del estilo sql, alguien podria explicarme como podria modificar esas consultas?

en crearLista reposa el siguiente codigo...

```
private List<Producto> crearListaProducto(String sucursal, IConsultaProductosRms consultaRms, List<String>
        listaBarra, String estatusProducto) {
    Producto producto = new Producto();
    List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    logger.info("Antes de la ejecutar crearListaProducto" + estatusProducto + ", " + sucursal + ", "
            + listaBarra);
    for (String codigoBarra : listaBarra) {

        producto = consultaRms.consultaProducto(em, codigoBarra, sucursal);
        producto.setStatusProducto(estatusProducto);

        productos.add(producto);
    }
    logger.info("Despu\u00E9s de la ejecutar consultaProductoPromocion retorna: "+ productos);
    return productos;
}
```

realmente lo que puedo ver es que crea la lista con los parametros que recibe y no se mucho, pero luego veo que envia el codigo de barra y hace uso de EM que tengo entendido es el EntityManager, pero a la final no logro ver el query como tal, que en la documentacion de la aplicacion es asi

```
SELECT DISTINCT temp.codigoPrincipal,temp.item
FROM (SELECT  tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal,
tmp_barra_primaria.item
FROM item_master       im, vat_item          vi, store             s,
      uda_item_lov      uil, rpm_future_retail rfr2, (
      SELECT decode(im.item_number_type, 'ITEM', im.item, im.item_parent)
      codigoPrincipal,im.item, im.item_desc descripcionLarga, im.short_desc
      descripcionCorta
      FROM item_master im
WHERE im.item_parent = ?1  ) tmp_barra_primaria
LEFT OUTER JOIN(item_loc il) ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = il.item
      AND il.loc = ?2) LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_future_retail rfr)
ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rfr.item AND rfr.location = ?2 AND
TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <=
TO_DATE(rfr.action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND (to_date(sysdate) - to_date(rfr.
      action_date)) >= 0) LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile) ON (
      tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rpile.item
      AND rpile.location = ?2
      AND TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') between TO_DATE(rpile.
      detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      AND to_date(rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
      WHERE im.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal
      AND vi.item = im.item
      AND s.store = ?2
      AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region
      AND uil.item = im.item
      AND uil.uda_id = 3
      AND rfr2.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal
      AND rfr2.location = ?2
      AND (to_date(SYSDATE) - to_date(rfr2.action_date)) >= 0
ORDER BY (RFR2.ACTION_DATE) DESC ) TEMP
```

Ese es el que necesito modificar y no logro conseguir de esa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Se está ejecutando una petición AJAX al servidor. Exactamente, esta es la URL del servicio: ConsultasRms/tabla_consultaProductoPromocion.html. Esto se denota en la siguiente llamada de jquery:

```
$.post(
    'ConsultasRms/tabla_consultaProductoPromocion.html',
    //resto de parámetros...
```

Revisa en tu proyecto, en la parte de backend, algún controlador que atienda las peticiones POST para esta URL. Siguiendo esa traza encontrarás los queries, tablas y demás elementos asociados.

Basado en tu edición, se puede saber que tu aplicación está desarrollada usando el patrón de arquitectura de capas. Es decir, tu aplicación debe estar dividida en capas, una dedicada para atender el request, otra para manejar los queries, otra para aplicar las reglas de negocio, etc. Esto significa que no esperes que los queries estén en el mismo método o clase donde se encuentra el código para atender el request. De momento, tienes lo siguiente en tu controlador:

```
listaP.add(0, crearListaProducto(sucursal, consultaRms, listaBarra, "2"));
```

La línea invoca a un método `crearListaProducto`, el cual en su interior es el que debe encargarse de tener la lógica para poder crear la lista de productos con los parámetros que recibe. Te recomiendo que revises las fuentes de ese método, es probable que dentro de ello se encuentren más llamadas a otros métodos, posiblemente de otras clases. Al final, podrás dar cuenta del método que ejecuta el query para insertar en la base de datos. No lo has explicado, pero es probable que tu aplicación utilice algún framework para operar contra la base de datos como JPA/Hibernate o MyBatis, por lo cual la sentencia `INSERT` no esté escrita explícitamente en el código.

Comment: gracias amigo edite la respuesta con lo que encontre de lado de backend, pero no veo que sean las consultas clasicas de mysql con SELECT

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta basado en tu edición de la pregunta.

Comment: si amigo tienes razon el framework en el que se trabaja es Spring

Comment: Spring no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con la ejecución de queries. Spring JDBC sí, pero Spring core no.

Comment: modifique la pregunta con el contenido del crearListaProducto, aun sin poder ver los query como tal, me hablaron de usar un CRUD para poder comprender la estructura de este proyecto, recomendaciones? gracias

Comment: Parece que nunca antes has trabajado con JPA, ¿cierto? Bueno, si dices que tu cambio debe ser hecho en una consulta, quizás no tengas que ver el código del método crear (eso lo puse como ejemplo para que entiendas mejor cómo funciona ese código), es probable que lo que debas revisar sean los métodos `consultaXyz` como `consultaProductosPromocion` y `consultarProductosPromocionInactivos`.

Comment: en efecto nunca lo he trabajado amigo, y voy a seguir analizando el codigo y su funcionamiento, gracias por el apoyo y espero seguir contando con el mismo